# How to change the default epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z for LocalDateTime

Tags: java, time, epoch

In the [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) class, there is a method to convert epoch second and nano second to UTC time.

It looks like:

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond()
```

However, it obtains an instance of `LocalDateTime` using seconds from the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

Is there a way to modify 1970 to 1980 as the default instance?

I believe I need it to be changed since:

```
epoch seconds = 667662644 
epoch nanoseconds = 1165598
```

should come out to:

```
13:50:44.001165598 03/03/2001
```

but I am getting:

```
13:50:44.001165598 2/27/1991
```

Comment: Short answer: No! --- Long answer: If your epoch is not the same as the Java epoch, then it's up to you to apply the difference, e.g. the number of seconds between 1/1/1970 and 1/1/1980, which is 315532800.

Comment: @Andreas ok that makes sense. I will figure out the offset and then use LocalTimeClass. Appreciate the tip.

Comment: Note that 667662644 with epoch 1/1/1980 is 2/26/2001, not 3/3/2001. It would seem that the value given is not even for a Gregorian calendar with leap years.

Comment: @Andreas it appears the date used at the start was 01/06/1980, would that make more sense?

Comment: Wow, that is a **weird** epoch value! `LocalDateTime.of(1980, 1, 6, 0, 0).toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)` shows offset to be 315964800. Add that to your "epoch seconds" and you'll get what you want.

Comment: @Andreas wow it worked! Thank you immensely!

Comment: @JaredSmith I had a very similar issue with a 1979 epoch timestamp. I used the same approach and wrapped it all up in my own application specific Timestamp class to handle creation, pass them around my app, converting between Java epoch and the special epoch etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figure out the offset you need and add it to all the epoch seconds values before converting to a `LocalDateTime'.

The offset can be calculated once and then hard-coded as

```
public static final int EPOCH_OFFSET = nnnn;
```

Sample:

```
    Instant GPS = Instant.parse("1980-01-06T00:00:00Z");
    long    GPS_EPOCH = GPS.toEpochMilli();
    System.out.printf("%s %,d\n",GPS.toString(), GPS_EPOCH);
```

Output:

```
1980-01-06T00:00:00Z 315,964,800,000
```

Comment: Ok. thanks for your answer. Just to be clear, I need to find the amount of epoch seconds there are from 1970-01-01 to 1980-06-01 and that will be EPOCH_OFFSET, then just subtract that from the total epoch seconds?

Comment: @JaredSmith June 1st of 1980? Really?

Comment: You can get the offset by creating a `LocalDateTime` of the epoch you want and converting to Java epoch seconds.  Then _add_ that value to your time values that are based on your epoch to convert them to Java epoch.  I mistyped the operation in the original answer, I am fixing it.

Comment: @Andreas sorry i mistyped it should be Jan 6 of 1980

Comment: What is special about 6 Jan 1980?

Comment: @JimGarrison I am converting an old c++ project to Java, am not totally sure it significance of it, i think it has to do something with gps time.

Comment: Be very careful if using `LocalDateTime`.  It is quite likely the epoch is based on UTC, so make sure you have the offset correct.

Comment: @JimGarrison I think you are correct, I appreciate the heads up.

Comment: Seems right about GPS. http://www.oc.nps.edu/oc2902w/gps/timsys.html: *GPS Time is a uniformly counting time scale beginning at the 1/5/1980 to 1/6/1980 midnight.*

Comment: @JimGarrison you may want to add the code Andreas used to find the offset, it overall completes the question. Thank you for your help again!